# Calling dictionary function multiple times using the same key in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am having the following dictionary:

```
def func1(a):
  return a

dic = {
       'a' : (lambda: fucn1(2))
      }
```

I want to call func1 multiple times with different arguments using the same key.

```
dic = {
        'a' : (lambda: func1(2), lambda: func1(4))
      }
```

So the output is:

```
2
4
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it does what you want! No need of `lambda` functions here. Just call the functions required. Try running it.

```
def func1(a):
  return a

dic = {
   'a' : (func1(2),func1(4))
}
for i in dic:
    for j in dic[i]:
        print j
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not need a lambda:

```
dic = {'a':tuple(func(i) for i in range(4))}
>>> dic
{'a': (0, 1, 2, 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map :
`map(function_to_apply, list_of_inputs)`

```
squared = list(map(func1, items))
```

Or with dict :

```
squared ={'a': (map(func1, items))}
```

input :

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```